# How to show complete table using model in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My database table has 50 rows, how to show all the tables on view using model? When I tried to show the product data on view. It shows the last row of the table, how can I show all rows in the view?

```
//Model : Product Properties 

    public class AllItems
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Qty { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string ImgName { get; set; }
        public string PrdDesc { get; set; }
    }

//Controller : Product data action manager

        public ActionResult ViewAllItems()
        {
            string[] Name = new string[10];
            DataTable dtProducts = Data.GetAllItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < dtProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                AllItems allItems = new AllItems
                {
                    ID = dtProducts.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    Name = dtProducts.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    Qty = dtProducts.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                    Price = dtProducts.Rows[i][3].ToString(),
                    PrdDesc = dtProducts.Rows[i][4].ToString(),
                };
                ViewData["AllItems"] = allItems;
            }
            return View();
        }

//View to show the Product data

@{
   AllItems allItems = (AllItems)ViewData["AllItems"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    <table style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.ID</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.Name</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.Price</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.Qty</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.ImgName</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@allItems.PrdDesc</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br />
    </table>       
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can make an array of the model class and show the properties?

Comment: Because in your loop you declare `AllItems allItems = new AllItems` and then add it to `ViewData` using `ViewData["AllItems"] = allItems;` In each iteration you overwrite the previous value. You need to add the items to a collection and then assign the collection to `ViewData`. But use a model (`List<AllItems>`), and return the model to the view.

Comment: Thanks Stephen....I got your point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this. I modified your code to use model instead of ViewData.

```
 public class AllItems
        {
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Qty { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
            public string ImgName { get; set; }
            public string PrdDesc { get; set; }
        }

//Controller : Product data action manager

        public ActionResult ViewAllItems()
        {
            string[] Name = new string[10];
            DataTable dtProducts = Data.GetAllItems();

            List<AllItems> items = new List<AllItems>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dtProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                AllItems allItems = new AllItems
                {
                    ID = dtProducts.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    Name = dtProducts.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    Qty = dtProducts.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                    Price = dtProducts.Rows[i][3].ToString(),
                    PrdDesc = dtProducts.Rows[i][4].ToString(),
                };

                items.Add(allItems);

            }
            return View(items);
        }

//View to show the Product data

@model List<AllItems>



    @foreach (var item in model)
    {
    <table style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.ID</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.Name</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.Price</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.Qty</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.ImgName</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>@item.PrdDesc</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <br />
    </table>       
    }
```